# Optimized way of looking for a specific value in R across all the rows in a large matrix

Tags: r

I have a large sparse matrix 1M X 10 (1 Million rows and 10 columns), I want to look every row in the matrix for a value and create a new vector based on it. Below is my code. I am wondering if there is any way I can optimize it.

```
CreatenewVector <- function(TestMatrix){
    newColumn = c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(TestMatrix)){ ## Loop begins
        Value  = ifelse(1 %in% TestMatrix[i,],1,0)
        newColumn = c(newColumn,Value)
    } ##Loop ends 
    return(newColumn)
}
## SampleInput: TestMatrix = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), byrow = T, nrow = 4)

## Sampleoutput: = (1,1,1,0)
## In the input TestMatrix, each vector represents a row. for instance (1,0,0) is the first row and so on.
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input and desired output? It's difficult to understand your goal here.

Comment: `as.numeric(apply(TestMatrix, 1, function(x) any(x == 1)))`

Comment: @jdobres. I just edited it. I hope it is clear. Please do let me know if it isn't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rowSums(x == 1) > 0`

Comment: @Gregor, would you mind telling me why rowSums is effective that %in%?  I thought %in% looks for the first matching value where as rowSums looks for every value in the row. Please do let me know if I am wrong

Comment: @JasonMathews, I'm not using `rowSums` instead of `%in%`, I'm using `==` instead of `%in%`. I'm testing every element to see if it is `1`. The `rowSums` will count the number of 1's in each row, and then the `> 0 ` will return `TRUE` if there are 1 or more `1` values in the row.

Comment: `rowSums` will be more effective because it is well optimized. After some input checking, an internal C function is called.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated it before everyone down votes the same. and thanks @Gregor

Comment: Also, if you *are* using a real `sparse matrix` classed object, please update with a reproducible example using whichever sparse matrix package you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using a normal `matrix` object, not a special sparse matrix class, you should use `rowSums`.

```
rowSums(x == 1) > 0
```

if `x` is the name of your matrix. This will return a `logical` vector, you can easily coerce to `numeric` with `as.numeric()` if you prefer 1/0 to true/false.

---

To give some sense of timing I benchmarked first using a thousand row matrix, then a million row matrix:

```
gregor = function(x) {as.numeric(rowSums(x == 1L) > 0L)}

# original method in question
op1 = function(x){
    newColumn = c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){ ## Loop begins
        Value  = ifelse(1 %in% x[i,],1,0)
        newColumn = c(newColumn,Value)
    } ##Loop ends 
    return(newColumn)
}

# modified original:
# eliminated unnecessary ifelse
# pre-allocated result vector (no growing in a loop!)
# saved numeric conversion to the end
op2 = function(x){
    newColumn = logical(nrow(x))
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){ ## Loop begins
        newColumn[i]  = 1L %in% x[i,]
    } ##Loop ends 
    return(as.numeric(newColumn))
}

bouncy = function(x) {
    as.numeric(apply(x, 1, function(y) any(y == 1L)))
}
```

Here are the results for a thousand row matrix:

```
n = 1e3
x = matrix(sample(c(0L, 1L), size = n, replace = T), ncol = 4)
microbenchmark(gregor(x), op1(x), op2(x), bouncy(x), times = 20)

    # Unit: microseconds
#       expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval  cld
#  gregor(x)   12.164   15.7750   20.14625   20.1465   24.8980   30.410    20 a   
#     op1(x) 1224.736 1258.9465 1345.46110 1275.6715 1338.0105 2002.075    20    d
#     op2(x)  846.140  864.7655  935.46740  886.2425  951.4325 1287.075    20   c 
#  bouncy(x)  439.795  453.8595  496.96475  486.5495  508.0260  711.199    20  b
```

Using `rowSums` is the clear winner. I eliminated `OP1` from the next test on a million row matrix:

```
n = 1e6
x = matrix(sample(c(0L, 1L), size = n, replace = T), ncol = 4)
microbenchmark(gregor(x), op2(x), bouncy(x), times = 30)
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min        lq      mean    median         uq        max neval cld
#  gregor(x)   9.371777  10.02862  12.55963  10.61343   14.13236   27.70671    30 a  
#     op2(x) 822.171523 856.68916 937.23602 881.39219 1028.26738 1183.68569    30   c
#  bouncy(x) 391.604590 412.51063 502.61117 502.02431  588.78785  656.18824    30  b
```

Where the relative margin is even more in favor of `rowSums`.

Comment: I think this will coerce the sparse matrix into a dense matrix which seems like something one would like to avoid.

Comment: I agree, if OP really is using a sparse matrix class... the question is not specific on that point.